# Extract key, value from multiple columns field in Postgresql table

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jdbc

From previous post, I am able to extract the many values in json format in postgres table to normal column using

```
select *, "columns"->>'uid' as uid, "columns"->>'name' as name
from myTable;
```

```
id |                   columns             |         timestamp          | query_id | task_id
---+---------------------------------------+----------------------------+----------+---------
 1 | {"uid": "112", "name": "redis-server"}| 2018-07-18 18:45:39.045387 |        1 |      2
 2 | {"uid": "0", "name": "celery"}        | 2018-07-18 18:45:39.047671 |        1 |      2
 3 | {"uid": "111", "name": "post"}        | 2018-07-18 18:45:39.048218 |        1 |      2
 4 | {"uid": "111", "name": "post"}        | 2018-07-18 18:45:39.048732 |        1 |      2
```

but now i have more than 100 different(fieldsets like uid,name above) in json, is there a operator or script i can use for the mass extraction,

Comment: In SQL the number of columns must be known **before** the query is executed (when parsing the query). The only way to get a 100 columns is to list a 100 column in the SELECT part. If you want to do something dynamic, do that in Java, when you display the result.

Comment: You could try using a view as a convenient bridge between your funky "store anything" schema and your app